# Regex match except row['xyz']

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help matching a regex.

Example: "row['DEU'] + row['CYP'] + DE"

I want to be able to replace DE with row['DE'] without affecting row[xyz].

If I do a global search and replace, the first row is affected so I'm looking of help how to replace without affecting parts of the string which have row['xyz']

Comment: Sorry -  wasn't clear -  replace with row['DE']

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a pattern like this will work for you:

```
/\b(\w+)(?![['])\b/
```

This will match any whole word (where a 'word' consists one or more Latin letters, decimal digits, or underscores), as long as it is not followed by a `[` or `'` character, and captures it in group 1, so you can use `$1` to represent the captured word in the replacement string.

For example:

```
"row['DEU'] + row['CYP'] + DE".replace(/\b(\w+)(?![['])\b/g, "row['$1']")
// "row['DEU'] + row['CYP'] + row['DE']"
```

Alternatively, you could omit the capture group and use `$&` instead:

```
"row['DEU'] + row['CYP'] + DE".replace(/\b\w+(?![['])\b/g, "row['$&']")
// "row['DEU'] + row['CYP'] + row['DE']"
```